# Return Entire Row from Index Match Function Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

In Table 1:

- I have Product Segments 1-6 for Companies
- 1-8. Each have different products that they list, not necessarily in the same order.
  1-8. Each have different products that they list, not necessarily in the same order.

In Table 2:

- I would like to return a "True" or "False" if the company lists Product Segments A-F as one of their products. For example, in Table 2 for Product Segment A, company 1 would return "True" and company 4 would return "False"

I feel like an `=MATCH(J$2,INDEX($B$3:$G$10,MATCH($I3,$A$3:$A$10,0)),0)` function is exactly what I'm looking for, but unfortunately I cannot return an array with excel's INDEX function.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Please refer to the image below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/491Wk.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$3:$A$10=$I3)*($B$3:$G$10=J$2))>0
```

[image]